# CSS to remove link from image

Tags: css

I'm using woocommerce and on a product page if you click the main image a huge image pops up that is hard to move away from.  I would like to disable the link to that image.  I do not see any way to do this through wp or woocommerce.

the page is here: http://www.jonicdsynznxpressionz.com/cart/#!/oh-i-am-collection/nudelee-collection/

I've been trying code to remove it but no luck getting it to work :

```
 .woocommerce-main-image zoom a{
pointer-events: none; !important;
cursor: default; !important;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the a tag? Also, the `!important` should be before the semicolons, there should be only 1 semicolon per line

Comment: Did you try width:0px; ?

Comment: Just edit the template (html/php) and remove the link.  Or use javascript and remove the href.

Comment: `.woocommerce-main-image zoom a` should be `a.woocommerce-main-image.zoom`

Answer (score 2):

With the selector corrected, your code seems to do the trick:

```
a.woocommerce-main-image.zoom{
      pointer-events: none !important;
      cursor: default !important;
 }
```

Comment: `!important` - inside the first semi-colon

Comment: @Zach... it worked fine. I tested it in firebug before posting. There were, however, improperly placed semi-colons that I failed to notice in the OPs code. Edited to correct.

Comment: @Ted That's exactly what I was referencing

Comment: @Zach gotchya...cold meds are messin with my brain :P

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 .woocommerce-main-image.zoom {
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: default !important;
  }
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no should.